# I am trying to record chunks of video from a camera stream using ffmpeg, but clips are recorded in h264 bitstream instead of annexb(avc1) bitstream

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, libavcodec

I am using the following command

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video2 -c copy -strftime 1 -hls_flags second_level_segment_index -hls_init_time 3 -flags -global_header -f hls -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 3 -hls_segment_filename 'c_%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S_%%06d.mp4'  out.m3u8`

I have the requirement that bitstream should be avc1, but I have to run separate FFmpeg command to convert the recorded video slice to avc1

`ffmpeg -i h264.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -an out.h264`

For this, I have to wait for the conversion

How should I modify the first FFmpeg command so that I get avc1 bitstream video slices?

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video2 -c copy -strftime 1 -hls_flags second_level_segment_index -hls_init_time 3 -flags -global_header -f hls -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 3 -hls_segment_filename 'c_%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S_%%06d.mp4' out.m3u8`

and

`ffmpeg -i h264.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -an out.h264`

[image: Getting this (h264)]

I need avc1 bitstream

[image: Desired bitstream (avc1)]

Comment: MP4s store H.264 in avcc format. Save to `.ts`

Comment: .ts is also storing h.264.

Comment: Just a speculation, but have you tried `-hls_segment_type mpegts`? Also, I wonder if you can use `-hls_segment_options` to specify `bsf` option for segments

Comment: @kesh I used this command but it didn't help
`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video4 -c copy -strftime 1 -hls_flags second_level_segment_index -hls_init_time 3  -hls_time 3 -hls_ts_options bsf=h264_mp4toannexb  -hls_segment_filename 'c_%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S_%%06d.ts'  out.m3u8`

Comment: @MohammadUmar yes, TS store H.264 in avc1 format. No need for a bsf.

Comment: I am using this command but the output is H.264 in h264 format instead of H.264 in avc1

'fmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video4 -c copy -strftime 1 -hls_flags second_level_segment_index  -hls_time 3  -hls_segment_filename 'c_%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S_%%06d.ts'  out.m3u8'